# How to catch BadHttpRequestException thrown by invalid json body

Tags: c#, .net, exception, .net-core, minimal-apis

Im playing abit with the .NET minimal API.
Trying to catch this exception when Im passing "Price" as a string
I've got my DTO as follows:

```
public record TransactionCreateDto    
{
    public string Description { get; init; } = String.Empty;
    public string Store { get; init; } = String.Empty; 
    public double Price { get; init; }
    public string Date { get; init; } = String.Empty;
    public int PaymentTypeId { get; init; }
    public int CategoryId { get; init; }
    public bool Seen { get; init; }
}
```

Here is the flow:

```
...
app.MapPost("/transactions", TransactionsAPI.InsertTransaction);
...
```

And he insert transaction function:

```
public static async Task<IResult> InsertTransaction(TransactionCreateDto transactionDto, ITransactionRepository repo)
{
    try 
    {
    ...
    } 
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

Im sure there is a correct way to catch this exception.
Thanks alot!

Comment: That exception happens before the handler method is invoked. You can look into [custom exception handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-6.0) or manually parsing dto from request.

Comment: Thank you! wiil check it out!

Answer (score 1):

Since the exception is happening before your function is getting called, I prefer the following approach. It's not 100% by the playbook, but gives much more flexibility.

Lets assume this is your original signature:

```
public static async Task<IResult> InsertTransaction(TransactionCreateDto transactionDto)
```

So instead of getting the DTO, try to get [JObject](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_linq_jobject.htm).

```
public static async Task<IResult> InsertTransaction(Jobject json)
{
    try
    {
        var m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TransactionCreateDto>(json);
    }
    catch(SomeSpecificException es)
    {
      
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Ill try this approach aswell!

Comment: This will still throw if the json itself is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

If the situation you are trying to handle is that passed string is a valid number (i.e. you want to allow this), one option is to allow the serializer to handle such cases by configuring it (see [customizing json binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-6.0#customize-json-binding) doc and [`JsonNumberHandling` enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonnumberhandling?view=net-6.0)):

```cs
builder.Services.Configure<JsonOptions>(options =>
{
    options.SerializerOptions.NumberHandling = JsonNumberHandling.AllowReadingFromString;
});
```

Otherwise depending on the use case you can either handle the request parsing manually (custom serializer, [`BindAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-6.0#bindasync) convention, or just from the request) or use [custom error handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-6.0) (if you want just to process the error in some custom way).